# How to fix "method not applicable to arguments" problem in this code that uses generics

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to implement an iterate method to my linked list to make it more readable and more compact since it is used more than once. My problem with the code I assume is not properly understanding Java generics in terms of method declaration. This is the error I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: The method iterate(Nodes<T extends Nodes<T>>) in the type LinkedList<T> is not applicable for the arguments (Nodes<T>)
```

I tried messing around with expected datatypes and arguments but couldn't figure out what is the problem exactly. I checked some other questions but couldn't necessarily find what I asked for or maybe couldn't understand the explanations.

```
  public class LinkedList<T> extends ListTemplate<T>
     {
       Nodes<T> head;
       Nodes<T> tail;
//declaration of method
       private <T extends Nodes<T>> Nodes<T> iterate(Nodes<T> head)
     {
    Nodes<T>iterate=head;
    while(iterate.getNext()!=null)
     {
        iterate=iterate.getNext();
     }
    return iterate;
     }
//the method call
public void Enqueue(T data)
    {
        Nodes<T>new_node=new Nodes<T>(data);
        //head is set for null when list is empty
        if(head==null)
        {
        //if the list is empty both head and tail will box new_node
        head=new_node;
        tail=new_node;
        }
        //if we insert something to list head wont be null
        else if(head!=null)
        {
        tail=iterate(head);
        tail.setNext(new_node);
        }
}
```

The code works when I don't try to make a separate method and implement in code. The expected result making this method iterate through the list of nodes I provided and return the last node. I am not sure about my mistake, but probably a declaration is problematic.

Answer (score 2):

With this line:

```
private <T extends Nodes<T>> Nodes<T> iterate(Nodes<T> head)
```

You're declaring the `iterate` method to be generic, with its *own* `T` type parameter, which is different from the class `LinkedList`'s type parameter `T`.

Like the `Enqueue` method (which would normally be spelled in lowercase as `enqueue`), the `iterate` method can simply use the class-scoped `T` defined already.  Remove the `T` declaration on the `iterate` method:

```
private Nodes<T> iterate(Nodes<T> head)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're saying that T is both the type of the content of a node, *and* the type of the returned Nodes object.

```
   private <T extends Nodes<T>> Nodes<T> iterate(Nodes<T> head)
```

You could fix by saying this instead:

```
   private Nodes<T> iterate(Nodes<T> head)
```